Violentmonkey/tampermonkey script not working on facebook
id just like to preface this by saying im not a good coder by any means and still learning/very new.
Im trying to create a script that will automate some actions based on simple xpath retrieval and clicking inputs. For whatever reason, the script will not run on the website and I cant figure out why. If anyone knows if theres something wrong with my code let me know.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Boss automater
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       *://apps.facebook.com/kingdomsofcamelot*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @description Script that automates the boss battle mini-game
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Function to click an element within an iframe using XPath
    function clickElementInIframe(iframe, xpath) {
        const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        const element = iframeDocument.evaluate(xpath, iframeDocument, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        if (element) {
            element.click();
            console.log('Clicked element in iframe:', xpath);
        } else {
            console.log('Element not found in iframe:', xpath);
        }
    }

    // Wait for the page to fully load
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Find the subframe (iframe) that contains the game
        const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
        if (iframe) {
            // First click on the element with the XPath //*[@id="bossBanner"] inside the iframe
            clickElementInIframe(iframe, '//*[@id="bossBanner"]');

            // Second click after a 2-second delay inside the iframe
            setTimeout(function() {
                clickElementInIframe(iframe, '//*[@id="mainbody"]/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]');
            }, 2000); // 2-second delay before clicking the second element

            // Third click after an additional 2 seconds (total 4 seconds delay) inside the iframe
            setTimeout(function() {
                clickElementInIframe(iframe, '//*[@id="attackPopupActionButton"]');
            }, 4000); // 4-second delay total

            // Fourth click after another 2 seconds (total 6 seconds delay) inside the iframe
            setTimeout(function() {
                clickElementInIframe(iframe, '//*[@id="mainbody"]/div[10]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/a');
            }, 6000); // 6-second delay total
        } else {
            console.log('Iframe not found on the page.');
        }
    });
})();


There is no obvious reason why its not working to me. I looked in the console of the developers tool and this is the only thing relating to my script that I can see. Any ideas what this means and how I can resolve it?
enter image description here

you can't access a cross origin frame. Match your script to the target iframe instead.
